# Request Tracker for Users created without privileges

Tags: perl, ubuntu, rt

I have configured request tracker4 to be an interdepartmental helpdesk solution. The current setup is that users will login to RT using LDAP. Once logged in there account is automatically created. However, their account is created with no privileges.

To fix this I have been having to go to Tools-->Configuration-->Select then put in the users DN name and clicking add I then have to check the box "Let this user be granted rights (Privileged)" I have also tried setting Set($AutoCreate, Privileged); but no luck.

I looked at the user accounts in the sqlite database and noticed that when new user logs in they are indeed created in the database. But with no privileges.

```
709|tuser3|*NO-PASSWORD*|||||||tuser3|||||||tuser3||tuser3|||||||||||||1|2013-03-08 13:47:38|1|2013-03-08 13:47:38
791|Mayra|*NO-PASSWORD*||||Mayra@**************||Main Office|Mayra Hernandez|||||||Mayra||Mayra||**************|||||||||||1|2013-04-03 21:46:36|1|2013-04-03 21:46:36
797|sdrakeford|*NO-PASSWORD*||Autocreated when added as a watcher||sdrakeford@**************|||Sophia C. Drakeford|||||||sdrakeford||sdrakeford|||||||||||||1|2013-04-04 13:18:58|1|2013-04-04 13:18:58
827|Robert.Troy|*NO-PASSWORD*||||Robert.Troy@*******************||Main Office|Robert Troy|||||||Robert.Troy||Robert.Troy||***************|||||||||||1|2013-04-04 16:11:58|1|2013-04-04 16:11:59
```

Am I missing something, because usually these things are quite obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`$AutoCreate` option](http://bestpractical.com/rt/docs/latest/RT_Config.html#AutoCreate) takes a hashref with all of the default options you want to pass to the User Create method. Try something like:

```
Set($AutoCreate, {
    Privileged => 1
});
```

(As an aside, it's generally not recommended to run a production instance on sqlite. You might want to consider converting to MySQL or Postgres.)

Comment: Thank you so much that worked perfectly. I would vote++ you but my rep is still too low.